# How to generate a dynamic URL using <dsp:a> in Oracle Commerce(ATG)

Tags: java, jsp, atg, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

I'm trying to display list of products in a jsp using ProductLookup droplet as shown below. I'm also trying to give a hyperlink to navigate to product details page of the individual product.

```jsp
<dsp:droplet name="/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductLookup">
    <dsp:param param="element.id" name="id"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="output"><br/>
    <dsp:a href="display_product.jsp?itemId=${id}">  
    Product display Name: 
    <b><dsp:valueof param="element.displayName"/></b><br/>
    Product description Name:
    <dsp:valueof param="element.description"/>
    </dsp:a>
    </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

However, I'm facing issue while passing the id of the product to `href` tag of `dsp:a`. The resultant HTML has hardcoded `${id}` as `display_product.jsp?itemId=${id}`. I'm getting list of products, but the URL is where I'm facing issue. How do I pass the value in `element.id` into the `href` attribute of `dsp:a`?

I've also tried the following, but no success.

1.

```jsp
<dsp:a href="display_product.jsp?itemId=<%=out.print(element.id) %>">
```

2.

```jsp
<dsp:a href="display_product.jsp?itemId=<%=out.print(id) %>">
```

3.

```jsp
<dsp:getvalueof var="id" id="id" >
            <dsp:a href="display_product.jsp?itemId=${id}">
            Product display Name: 
            <b><dsp:valueof param="element.displayName"/></b><br/>
            Product description Name:
            <dsp:valueof param="element.description"/>
            </dsp:a>
            </dsp:getvalueof>
```

Comment: option 3 was your closest bet to having something working... but instead of `id="id"` it should have been `param="id"`

Comment: An observation: Try and get into the habit of using `<dsp:a *page*=` instead of `href`. For relative urls it will resolve correctly while for absolute urls it will add the context path.

Comment: Hi thr , i have tried the Option 3 with your suggestion (param="id") but it still not working :( .thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pass parameters to another page you simply use the `<dsp:param>` tag as per the code fragment below (nested within your ProductLookup droplet):

This is the old-school ATG approach:

```jsp
 <dsp:a href="display_product.jsp">
     Product Name: <b><dsp:valueof param="element.displayName"/></b><br/>
     Product description: <dsp:valueof param="element.description"/>
     <%-- this will pass the itemId parameter and value--%>
     <dsp:param name="itemId" param="element.id"/>
 </dsp:a>
```

The preferred approach is to use jstl EL variables which makes your jsp's cleaner and easier to read, as well as allowing more flexibility when referring to the values:

```jsp
<%-- name the "element" and convert to a map  --%>
<dsp:tomap var="product" param="element" recursive="false"/>
<dsp:a href="display_product.jsp">
     Product Name: <b>${ product.displayName }</b><br/>
     Product description: ${ product.description }
     <dsp:param name="itemId" value="${ product.id }"/>
</dsp:a>
```

I have used `recursive="false"` in the above example because you are only referencing to direct properties of a product.  If you wanted to refer to properties of properties then you could do something like this (the code below is not tested but should give you the general idea):

```jsp
<dsp:tomap var="product" param="element" recursive="true"/>
<dsp:img page="${ product.image.url }">
```

**UPDATE:**

As I continue to be amazed how few people understand how to do even the most basic thing such as passing parameter, I have included other DSP tags which can be used in conjunction with the `<dsp:param>`

You can pass parameters for included JSP fragments which use the `<dsp:include>`

```jsp
<dsp:tomap var="product" param="element" recursive="false"/>
<dsp:include page="fragments/myfragment.jsp">
    <dsp:param name="itemId" value="${ product.id } />
</dsp:include>
```

This approach will work for these tags as well:

- `<dsp:iframe>`
- `<dsp:img>`
- `<dsp:link>`

Comment: It worked Thank you , but it worked when i have used param="elment.id" instead of "paramavalue" attribute

Comment: @MrLore very nice explanation appreciated.Thanks a ton.

Comment: @HariKiranMutyala you are thanking the wrong person.  Stick around you will learn how this works ...

Answer (score 1):

@Bated answer is pretty thorough but want to add some additional information about why it is so important to use the ATG `dsp` tags to achieve this.

---

ATG maintains your session in two ways:

1. Via the jsessionid stored in a cookie
2. Via the jsessionid stored in the query string

By using the `<dsp>` tags you ensure that you maintain the users session as it is quite possible that the user has cookies disabled and the `dsp` tags will revert to using the query string.

Using the html anchor tag is unsafe for this reason as the users session will only be maintained if they have cookies enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following snippet. You need to use dsp:getvalueof as shown below.

```
<dsp:droplet name="/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductLookup">
    <dsp:param param="element.id" name="id"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="output"><br/>
       <dsp:getvalueof id="id" param="element.id" idtype="java.lang.String">
           <dsp:a href="display_product.jsp?itemId=<%=id%>">
               Product Name: <b><dsp:valueof param="element.displayName"/></b><br/>
               Product description: <dsp:valueof param="element.description"/>
           </dsp:a>
       </dsp:getvalueof>
    </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `<%=id%>` also be `${id}`? Using _scriptlets_ in your JSP should really be discouraged.