# How to pass parameters via dsp:iframe to the iframe

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

I want to pass `<dsp:iframe>` tag to the src jsp. As per ATG documentation I can use `<dsp:param>` tags to pass params and then use their value in the src of iframe. Can someone provide me with an example  how this can be done?

Newbie in ATG

Answer (score 0):

Below is some sample code:

```
<dsp:iframe page="homepage.jsp">Go to your home page
     <dsp:param name="city" beanvalue="Profile.homeAddress.city"/>
</dsp:iframe>
```

The parameter is passed as any parameter is passed in ATG and can be retrieved [in the same way any parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510040/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-url-using-dspa-in-oracle-commerceatg/25518007#25518007) is retrieved (assuming your iframe reference another JSP in your application.  If the  references an external page the parameter should be retrieved from the query string.

Not sure you have done any research as this is clearly defined in the [oracle commerce help](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Platform.11-1/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s0210passingpageparameters01.html).